# push new element to array of obj in multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which is like

```js
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "name1",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/3.jpg",
        "price" : 200
    }
  ]
```

and I want to add new element to each obj like this, "count" : 12, I tried to do this using .push but it will add the count to the end of array instead of adding it to each obj, How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you add your JavaScript code, or a Plunkr with your code as it is currently?

Comment: By the way, its not really a multidimensional array (that would be [[],[],[]]) , its an array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(elem of array){
  elem["count"]=12;
}
//OR
for(key in array){
array[key]["count"]=12;
}
//OR
array.forEach(function(elem){
  elem["count"]=12;
}
//OR
newarray=array.map(function(el){
return el["count"]=12,el;
}
```

You cannot add to multiple elems, you have to loop trough and add to each one.
It depends on you wich way you go (of the upper examples).

Also push is made for Arrays not for Objects (push adds just a value not a key, an object needs a key value pair).

Answer (score 1):

For you will be easy to use map. Try this:

```
var result = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "name1",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/3.jpg",
        "price" : 200
    }
  ].map(function(item) {
    item["test"] = "new item";
        return item; 
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add properties of object using forEach method.

and **push** is not method to add property of an object.

```js
var arr=[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "name1",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/3.jpg",
        "price" : 200
    }
  ]
arr.forEach(function(a){a["count"] = 12})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add a new property with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: "name1", description: "Lorem ipsum ...", image: "sampledata/products/1.jpg", price: 10 }, { id: 2, title: "name2", description: "Lorem ipsum ...", image: "sampledata/products/2.jpg", price: 100 }, { id: 3, title: "name3", description: "Lorem ipsum ...", image: "sampledata/products/3.jpg", price: 200 }];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.count = 12;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As below..

```
var arr=[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "name1",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/3.jpg",
        "price" : 200
    }
  ];
arr.forEach(function (obj) {
  obj.count = 12;
});

alert(arr[0].count);
alert(arr[1].count);
alert(arr[2].count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   let arr = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "name1",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/1.jpg",
        "price" : 10
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/2.jpg",
        "price" : 100
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nesciunt hic aut? Saepe nihil autem nesciunt, ab quisquam animi, aperiam fugit? Ut velit a, in perspiciatis error inventore. Dolorum, eligendi.",
        "image" : "sampledata/products/3.jpg",
        "price" : 200
    }
  ]
arr.forEach((val) =>{val['count'] = 12;})
console.log(arr);
```

hope this helps....